# JMS QueueRequestor and deleted Destination

Tags: queue, jms

I'm using Activem MQ 5.3.1
My configuration is good for classical async messaging
I try to use a QueueRequestor
The message is effectively sended, recieved.
But when it's time to answer on the temp queue i've got this exception raised
javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Cannot publish to a deleted Destination: temp-queue://ID:......

the destination doesn't exist

I'm using the default conf for activemq
Any idea??

Comment: maybe a portion of answer
http://blogs.sun.com/fkieviet/entry/request_reply_from_an_ejb

Comment: aditionnally i can say the temp queue is created when try the same on one broker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find my answer
the implementation of queuerequestor is made for send and recieve on the same jmsSession.
That's why the reciever of the requestor never seen any message, and why the temp destination could'n be use topublish message

My solution is to create a requestor with two session.
The actuall implmentation will be very similar to the one on the blog post above